# How to enumerate the sentences of a paragraph separated one-by-one with SpaCy

Tags: python, spacy

I want to read the sentences of a paragraph separated one-by-one with SpaCy. Yet, when trying to enumerate the sentences I enumerate the words rather than the sentences. Indeed,

```
text = predicted.iloc[0,5]
sentences = spacy_nlp(text)
print(sentences)
for i,sent in enumerate(sentences):
    print("---",i,"---")
    print(sent)
```

Gives the sentences made by SpaCy first :

```
['Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ bee-YON-say) (born September 4, 1981) is an American singer, songwriter, record producer and actress.', "Born and raised in Houston, Texas, she performed in various singing and dancing competitions as a child, and rose to fame in the late 1990s as lead singer of R&B girl-group Destiny's Child.", "Managed by her father, Mathew Knowles, the group became one of the world's best-selling girl groups of all time.", 'Their hiatus saw the release of Beyoncé\'s debut album, Dangerously in Love (2003), which established her as a solo artist worldwide, earned five Grammy Awards and featured the Billboard Hot 100 number-one singles "Crazy in Love" and "Baby Boy".']
```

But then it enumerate on the words rather than on the sentences:

```
--- 0 ---
[
--- 1 ---
'
--- 2 ---
Beyoncé
--- 3 ---
Giselle
--- 4 ---
Knowles
--- 5 ---
-
--- 6 ---
Carter
...
```

#### PS:

Thanks to X ideas to convert it to a list enabled me to write it sentence by sentence.

Yet the whole idea was to proceed it to `nltk_spacy_tree()` function and it seems it only accepts objects of type `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` so I did the following which doesn't seem to be very adapted. It seems too complex :

```
text = predicted.iloc[0,5]
sentences = list(spacy_nlp(text))
sentences = en_nlp(predicted["context"][0].lower()).sents
#print(type(en_nlp(sentences)))
for i,sent in enumerate(sentences):
    print("---",i,"---")
    print(en_nlp(str(sent)))
    sent = en_nlp(str(sent))
    tree = nltk_spacy_tree(sent)
    print(tree)
```

Comment: Well i used your list and replicated the code you have written in python 2.7. I was able to enumerate on sentences. Could you please share the output of `type(sentences)` and `len(sentences)`.

Comment: @SagarDawda Yes, 162 <class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>. I used Python 3

Comment: If could convert <class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'> to a python list I guess your solution might work. So `sentences = list(spacy_nlp(text))` should do the job I guess. Can you give it a try?

Comment: did the conversion to list work?

Comment: @SagarDawda Yes, thanks! I updated the question to see what it enabled me to do. It seems I complicated my life.

Comment: Great. Glad you found a solution